# searching and entity references

Tags: 7, search, entities

I have two content types documents and authors.
When creating a document a selection list of entity reference's to authors is used to select the author.

Searches for the author name find the correct author, but do not find the document that has an entity reference to the author. How do I get the search engine to to display both the author and the documents the author is referenced from.

EX Book "GOOD BOOK" is has an entity reference to Author "TOM".

When I do a search for TOM I get the "TOM"'s authors information but NOT an entry for "GOOD BOOK"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to configure your search view modes.

For each of your content types, visit the **Magage Display** page, eg admin/structure/types/manage/page/display

Unfurl **Custom Display Settings**, check **Search Index** and **Search Result**, and save.

Then for each, configure the search view modes.  **Search Index** will be used to build up the text that gets indexed.  Add / remove fields as needed.  The **Search Result** will be used to display the search results.